# Swift Closure Expression

Tags: arrays, swift, callback, closures

I have to download some names into an array but I don't know exactly how many names will get downloaded. Only after all the names are downloaded I need a custom function to run.

I used a closure to call the custom function but what happens is once the first name is downloaded, my custom function is getting called immediately, then the second name is downloaded, then the custom function is called again etc.

I need the custom function to get called only after all the names are downloaded into the array, not after each name is downloaded. Where am I doing something wrong at?

This is what I'm getting:

```
Mable
This should only print once not three times
Marlene
This should only print once not three times
Moses
This should only print once not three times
```

This is what I want:

```
Mable
Marlene
Moses
This should only print once not three times
```

If possible, i would like the issue to be resolved inside: addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure

Code:

```
//There actually can be 1 or 100 names but I just used 3 for the example
var randomNames = ["Mable", "Marlene", "Moses"]
var nameArray = [String]()

func addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure(name: String, completionHandler: (success:Bool)->()){
    nameArray.append(name)
    print(name)

    let flag = true
    completionHandler(success:flag)
}

func customFunction(){
    print("This should only print once not three times")
}

for name in randomNames{
    addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure(name){

      //Shouldn't this run only after the array is filled?
      (success) in
      if success == true{
          customFunction()
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `== true` to check a `Bool`. Just use the `Bool` directly. Also, avoid naming things like `nameArray`. Just call it `names`. The plurality implies it's a collection like an Array.

Comment: @Alexander Momchliov thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure` actually only adds a single name, and you call it once per name. If you call your completion handler in there, it'll be called ... once per name. You need to redesign this so the closure is called after all the names are added.

Here's how I would do it:

```
//There actually can be 1 or 100 names but I just used 3 for the example
var randomNames = ["Mable", "Marlene", "Moses"]
var globalNames = [String]()

func add(names: [String], completionHandler: ( _ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    globalNames.append(contentsOf: names)

    completionHandler(true)
}

add(names: randomNames) { success in
    if success {
        print("Finished")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're over thinking this. By what you described, you don't need a completion handler, or any of this. What is the source of the "random names"?

Comment: So why isn't that just an array?

Comment: `globalNames += photos.flatMap{ $0.metadata?.dowbloadUrl()?.absoluteString }`

Comment: And then on the next line do whatever you need to do. No need for a completion handler

Comment: Why are you generating the array of string with a loop, and not just map/flatmap?

Comment: Oh man. Definitely learn about map, reduce, filter and flatmap. They almost completely eliminate the need for loops in simple translation and filtering operations on sequences. Map/flatmap is also faster than  manually looping and appending

Comment: Alex THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! I'm going to read up on it over the weekend. I appreciate your help. God Bless!!! Btw I deleted the other comments to prevent us from getting forced into a private convo. Thanks again :)

Comment: Don't delete comments, they maintain historical record that may be relevant to future readers.

Comment: Also, are you aware of the performance issue with repeatedly using `append` on an array?

Comment: I'm not aware of any performance issues. Why would that happen? But every time the user leaves the scene I empty the array so when they come back to the scene it's append it's happening on an empty array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128313/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-lance-samaria).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding the `for` loop in the `addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure` method. Then, you can call the completion handler after all names have been added.

```
var randomNames = ["Mable", "Marlene", "Moses"]
var nameArray = [String]()

func addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure(completionHandler: (success: Bool) -> ()) {
    for name in randomNames {
        nameArray.append(name)
    }
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

Then, call your custom function from the completion handler like so:

```
addAllNamesToArrayThenRunClosure() { success in
    self.customFunction()
}
```